# the string is too long for the length specified by the column definition :- While creating a setup package

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

While trying to create a setup file using VS2012, I get the error:

> The string is too long for the length specified by the column definition".

Its a simple C# with MS-Access 2007 Database Windows Form Application.

One More Error that pops up if i select another location:

> "Error 3   -5047: Cannot create directory c:\users\rezr\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Setup1\Setup1\Setup1\Express\CD_ROM\DiskImages\DISK1\program files\REZRTECH INC\My Product Name\Campus Database System\Campus Database System\Campus Database System\Express\CD_ROM\DiskImages\DISK1. The path exceeds 248 character limit specified by the operating system. Change the build location of the current release to a shorter path to resolve this issue.  ISEXP : error : -5047: Cannot create directory c:\users\rezr\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Setup1\Setup1\Setup1\Express\CD_ROM\DiskImages\DISK1\program files\REZRTECH INC\My Product Name\Campus Database System\Campus Database System\Campus Database System\Express\CD_ROM\DiskImages\DISK1. The path exceeds 248 character limit specified by the operating system. Change the build location of the current release to a shorter path to resolve this issue."

System details:

- Processor : AMD Athlon X250 (X86) 3.2 GHZ
- RAM: 2GB.
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Yes, CPU frequency apparently is an important factor influencing your issue. Sorry, but you haven't even provided info like *where* the error occurs.

Comment: the String error pops up when i try to add folder during "add Application files " page. 

i copied the entire folder to D Drive(thinking it will be shorter path ) but that doesn't help at all

Comment: Maybe you should also try to get rid of the directories created multiple times like Setup1 and Campus Database System.

Comment: As @OndrejTucny stated your system details are not related to your question.

Comment: @user3198759: So you actually want to add another directory to an allready too long path?

Comment: Seems to be working, i shortened the Project name to its initials..

but is there no other way to create package with lengthy names?

Comment: But !?! You poste the answer! "The path exceeds 248 character limit specified by the operating system. Change the build location of the current release to a shorter path to resolve this issue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure the project path is too long (248 characters) as the error message explicitly states.

Copy your project to a different location resulting in a much shorter path and it should work.

Also such long paths are not nice to navigate.

Edit:

 The error message actually also states the solution:

> The path exceeds 248 character limit specified by the operating
>   system. ***Change the build location of the current release to a shorter
>   path to resolve this issue.***

Also copying the directory structure

> Setup1\Setup1\Setup1\Express\CD_ROM\DiskImages\DISK1\program files\REZRTECH INC\My Product Name\Campus Database System\Campus Database System\Campus Database System\Express\CD_ROM\DiskImages\DISK1

to a different location will be most propably to little when you have filenames longer than 50 characters.

Comment: Seems to be working, i shortened the Project name to its initials..

but is there no other way to create package with lengthy names?

Comment: I dont think you need to shorten the project name but you should rethink your directory structure as it looks strange to me. And no there is no workaround for this restriction for legacy file paths.